# Firefox quit by Ctrl-q without ask, though showQuitWarning is set to true

Tags: firefox

The question itself is in the title.
I have and use two Firefox profiles, and second one is configured same way, but ask every time when I mispress ctrl-q.
How can I disable ctrl-q?

Comment: What OS are you using?  What version of Firefox?

Comment: @ficer1234 It's 62.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a longstanding complaint with Firefox.  There were several highly-rated extensions to disable Ctrl-Q, but they're not compatible with Firefox Quantum.  There is an extension that's compatible, but it's been panned by a majority of reviewers as not working.  I'm not aware of any other extensions.

Aside from extensions, there have been several approaches to dealing with this.  One is to reassign the key combination with a custom keyboard shortcut.  Depending on your OS, you may be able to do this natively, or you could use something like AutoHotKey.  People often remap Ctrl-Q to just beep or play one of the system sounds.

However, it may be an acceptable workaround to just control what Firefox does when you accidentally hit Ctrl-Q.  That is affected by a number of settings.  They've moved around a bit, and vary by platform, so you may need to check a few places to find them on your version.

Ctrl-Q just closes the window.  How that affects Firefox depends on the preferences and configuration settings.  The first setting that determines things is whether you set Firefox to `Restore previous session` at startup (depending on your version, it might also be labeled something like "Show my windows and tabs from last time".  On my system, this is under `Edit | Preferences | General: Startup`.

If you set it to restore the previous session, Firefox keeps track of the open tabs and isn't concerned with warning you before closing.  I believe that in this case, Firefox ignores the other settings concerning warnings.  With this setting, closure is considered harmless, so no matter how you close, you won't get a warning.  Just open Firefox again to return to where you were.

If you want a warning, you need to disable the `Restore previous session` preference.  In that case, you can use History to reopen tabs, but that won't remember the status of each tab.

With `Restore previous session` at Startup **disabled**, there are several settings that control warnings.  The warnings allow you to cancel the closure if it wasn't intended (unless you get in the habit of automatically overriding the warning).  These are in `about:config` (which you enter like a URL).  Accept the warning about voiding your warranty, that's just to get your attention (although it's possible to mess up Firefox in non-obvious ways if you start playing with settings that you aren't familiar with).  The settings are in alphabetical order, and you can also search.

- Find `browser.showQuitWarning` and verify that it's set to `True` (you can toggle it to True if it isn't).
- Find `browser.tabs.warnOnClose` and verify that it's set to `True` (you can toggle it to True if it's not).  Depending on your version, you might have an option under `Edit | Preferences | Tabs` worded something like "Warn me when closing multiple tabs".  I'm not sure if this is the same setting, but it can't hurt to set or verify it in both places.

I suspect that in your case, quitting on Ctrl-Q without a warning, even with browser.showQuitWarning True, was because that profile was set to restore the session on restart.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `Restore previous session` worked like a charm!